# prove or disprove the following statement on topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

prove or disprove the following:

Let $(X, \mathscr{T}_1)$ and $(Y, \mathscr{T}_2)$ be topological spaces and suppose that $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a function that is $\mathscr{T}_1$ − $\mathscr{T}_2$
continuous. If $A \subseteq Y$ , then $f^{-1}[\operatorname{int}(A)] \subseteq \operatorname{int}(f^{-1}[A)]$

my work:

I think , it is true statement

and my proof is:

As stated $\operatorname{int}(A)$ is open in $Y$,
So that $f^{-1}[\operatorname{int} (A)]$  is open in $X$,
Since $f^{-1}[\operatorname{int}(A)] \subseteq f^{-1}[A]$  and $\operatorname{int}(f^{-1}[A)]]$  is the greatest open set contained in  $f^{-1}[A]$

Thus,$f^{-1}[\operatorname{int}(A)] \subseteq \operatorname{int}(f^{-1}[A])$.

Answer (score 1):

That proof looks good, although it should say that $\text{int}[f^{-1}(A)]$ is the largest open set contained in, not containing, $f^{-1}(A)$. Also, in the future please write your questions in Tex

Comment: I edited and testified it.